# Why can't I remove access for that specific field in a profile?

Tags: permissions, profile, permission-sets, field-level-security, fls

I have a custom object "Ticket" and I want to remove "Edit Access" for a standard profile "Standard Platform User" for the field "Approved To Start Work" but I can't change this:

[image]

I can change this for other fields but not for that field. That field is from a managed package (but I can change access for other fields from that managed package)

What can be the reason why I can't change that field? Are there some settings that determine what fields can be changed?

I have System Administrator profile

Comment: Is "Approved To Start Work" profile part of the manage package ?

Comment: @ Piyush I don't know where to check this, I don't see any pop-up which would indicate that, but it could be the reason - because I can edit other fields from that profile but not this field

Answer (score 1):

You can't able to change the field level security for mandatory fields for any objects.

In your case, `Approved To Start Work` is mandatory field at `Ticket` object level. So you can't able to change the FLS for all the profiles.

Comment: Yes - this was the issue - the field is required - this is why it can't be changed.
What would be the best way to block access to edit that field? Creating a validation rule?

Comment: @Fgh999, yes can use validation rule to restrict the user to edit the field.